# Loop through a collection of Arrays and return named key value pairs (Laravel/Eloquent)

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent

I am working with Laravel and currently I have an eloquent Collection being returned with 3 arrays within the collection. Within each array are nested Model collections.

The structure is like so:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1905 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => app\Models\User {#1804 ▶}
    1 => app\Models\User {#1805 ▶}
    2 => app\Models\User {#1806 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Each user is like so when expanded

```
#attributes: array:3 [▼
        "user_id" => 12345
        "first_name" => "John"
        "last_name" => "Doe"]
```

What I want to have returned is an array with just the `user_id => 12345` for all the users.

I tried the traditional `foreach` but the index keep returning as `0 => 12345` instead of `user_id` as my key. I also tried `pluck()` to pull the `user_id` but I got the same result of a numeric `key`.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this using eloquent?

Comment: use `pluck('user_id')->values()`

Comment: @KamleshPaul if I use `pluck('user_id')->values()` on my collection and then add on `toArray()` it returns an array but with numerical keys. `array:2 [▼
  0 => 12345
  1 => 12346
]` but I want the `0,1` to be `user_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pluck would not work since `user_id` is the value from the collection you are extracting.

Why not just do a select with only the fields you want...Instead of removing things from collection you don't need?

For example this would return an array of arrays with a key id and value being that id.

```
User::select('id')->get()->toArray();
```

```
 [
     [
       "id" => 1,
     ],
     [
       "id" => 2,
     ],
]
```

But to do what you want given the data you have you could use `map` and return only the key-value data you need. Here is a short example:

```php
$collection = [
  [
    "user_id" => 12345,
    "first_name" => "John",
    "last_name" => "Doe",
  ],
  [
    "user_id" => 12346,
    "first_name" => "John 2",
    "last_name" => "Doe",
  ],
  [
    "user_id" => 12347,
    "first_name" => "John 3",
    "last_name" => "Doe",
  ],
];

collect($collection)->map(function ($user) {
  return [
    "user_id" => $user["user_id"],
  ];
});
```

Keep in mind this way from an start array so in your case I am assuming you be doing like:

```php
User::get()->map(function ($user) {
  return [
    'user_id' => $user->user_id,
  ];
});
```